# Xcode Swift: Login/Signup Page not displaying first due to slideoutmenu

Tags: ios, swift, slidingmenu

I'm in the process of creating an app using xcode/swift that implements both a sliding sidebar menu along with a login/signup process. The sliding sidebar menu functionality should only be accessible on the next view immediately after completing either the login or signup.

I followed the instructions for the Sliding Sidebar tutorial here: Ray Wenderlich - Sidebar Tutorial

Problem is -> My Sidebar menu functionality only works when the containing view is the first view displayed upon opening the app.

Sometimes this is OK because once a user is logged-in, the sidebar menu view is the first view displayed -- but this is not always the case -- Logged-out users must complete signup/login before they are able to access/transition to this view.

I did set the initial view of the app to point to my LoginViewController in the storyboard so I don't know why this would not load first!?

My guess is this has something to do with setting the rootviewcontroller in my AppDelegate.swift file.

AppDelegate.swift

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    let containerViewController = ContainerViewController()

    window!.rootViewController = containerViewController
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true

}
```

How can I enforce that the loginViewController get displayed first on application startup!?

Comment: Just instantiate your `loginVC` and make it your `rootViewController`, then from there instantiate your `containerViewController` and use `loginVC` to present it, you can make some `NSUserDefault` to check if user logged or not then straight present the `containerViewController` next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to set your rootViewController as loginVC so in your appDelegate file replace above method with

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

// replace names accordingly
let loginViewController = LoginViewController()

window!.rootViewController = loginViewController
window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

return true

}
```

now you should save state of the user in userDefaults or something. For example if the user in not logged in

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn)
```

and when user login to the app you can update the userDefault like so

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isUserLoggedIn")
```

so your final function should look like something this

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)


if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("isUserLoggedIn") == true{

    let containerViewController = ContainerViewController()

    window!.rootViewController = containerViewController
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    }
else {
    let loginViewController = LoginViewController()

     window!.rootViewController = loginViewController
     window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    return true

}
```